# Naming of Monte Carlo and Las Vegas Complexity classes

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

For Curiosity Sake, I was wondering if there was some history behind the naming of "Las Vegas" and "Monte Carlo" classes.

I've searched on the internet for quite some time now but I did not find a proper answer, is it just because they are probabilistic which gives them the "gambling" nature, or is there something more to the nomenclature?

Comment: [en.wikipedia on their relation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm#Relation_to_Monte_Carlo_algorithms)

Comment: Bellagio algorithms also make an appearance.